# How to use typeguards on class public functions and class variables

Tags: typescript

Assume following validator class

```
class Validator<T> {
  private readonly data: T;

  public constructor(data: T) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public isDefined(): this.data is NonNullable<T> { // This is invalid
    return typeof this.data !== 'undefined';
  }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to add non nullable typeguard to isDefined function for `this.data`. Example above is invalid and errors with following at `this.data`

```
(property) Validator<T>.data: T
Duplicate identifier 'data'.ts(2300)
All declarations of 'data' must have identical modifiers.ts(2687)
Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'data' must be of type 'T', but here has type 'any'.ts(2717)
validation.ts(11, 20): 'data' was also declared here.
```

I was planning to use this in scenario like following:

```
const myNumber: number | undefined = 1234;

if (new Validator(myNumber).isDefined()) {
  console.log(myNumber) // Typescript should only see this as number
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to do it via a method like that. I think the user type guards are only functions which can then affirm that one of the parameters is a given type. But I'm not sure the type system can handle taking a parameter as the constructor and then call a method. I think a workaround of sorts would be to have something like `getValid()` method that returns `number` when the value is valid or throws an exception if it's not valid. It's a bit ugly but `myValidNumber = new Validator(myNumber).getValid()` should be accepted by the type system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work only if you were referencing `validator.data` as opposed to referencing a free variable from the outer scope.

```
class Validator<T> {
  constructor(readonly data: T) {}

  isDefined(): this is Validator<NonNullable<T>> {
    return (
      this.data !== null && this.data !== undefined
    );
  }
}

declare const myNumber: number | undefined;

const validator = new Validator(myNumber);

if (validator.isDefined()) {
  validator.data;
}
```